# From Bitbucket Repos to Remote Host

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I need to synchronize my bitbucket repositary with my site on my hosting.
Is possible via git ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you just do a git pull on your host?

Comment: Your best bet is probably looking into a continuous integration setup such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to export the working tree: `git archive master | tar -x -C /somewhere/else` then ftp it to the hosting. You can make a script out of this to export the site to a hosting. All above is if you don't have ssh level access to your server.

If you do have ssh level access you can `git pull` from bitbucket on your hosting then use the anove export command to export the working tree to your site index folder.